# UE5 - Using "add force" to player for a thruster mechanic

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

Trying to add a "thruster" or "booster" mechanic to the player character in Unreal. When hitting the input, the player gains a short boost of speed in their current movement direction.

I first tried the "AddImpulse" node, which worked, but since it's instantaneous, the player zips around too quickly. I want to use the "Add Force" node instead to more gradually add a sustained impulse over a short duration (< 1 sec), but I can't seem to find a proper method to repeatedly fire the node over that time.

I've looked at using Event Tick, but I can't make that make sense while inside an InputAction function, and UE5's collection of loop functions also don't quite make sense for this specific function.

This seems like it should be a simple use case, so it feels like I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the "thruster" or "booster" mechanic I would use LaunchCharacter(Vector LaunchVelocity,...args) function in Character.  All you probably need is the LaunchVelocity param.  A good starting point for LaunchVelocity would look like: CapsuleComp.GetForwardVector.Normalize * 400 + Vector(0,0,400).  This can all be done in BP

Additionally, you may want to play around with  CharacterMovementComponent.AirControl.

[Character docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Character/) where you can look up LaunchCharacter(). and [CharacterMovementComp](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/UCharacterMovementComponent/).  I would recommend getting familiar with inherited functions. Hope that helps!